# Android burger/arrow icon dynamic change color

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

I want to change color of burger/arrow icon of navigation drawer. I know I can change it in styles, but I want change it dynamically in java. Did anybody know how to do this?

Comment: What code is not working?

Comment: have same problem here. and @moffeltje guess Rafal have no lucky looking for code for it (same here).. it's been 3 hours looking for it.

Comment: Rafal if you found an answer, can you post it or work around for it?

Comment: No i dont found how to do this, only way to colorize that icon is change theme in resource:/

Comment: I got it, I'm trying to change all elements of toolbar dynamically. I'm missing right now ActionMenuViews [look at my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569989/change-drawer-burger-arrow-icon-dynamically-without-styling-toolbar).

Answer (score 10):

Using **appcompat-v7:23.0.1** next code worked for me:

```
int color = Color.parseColor("#FFEEEE00");
final PorterDuffColorFilter colorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
    final View v = toolbar.getChildAt(i);

    if (v instanceof ImageButton) {       
        ((ImageButton) v).setColorFilter(colorFilter);
    }
}
```

Use it in `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

Comment: Did find it useful for you?, do you need something else or its fine. [Remember to accept the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: This works, thanks. And needs to be set in onCreateOptionsMenu, otherwise it doesnt work. At least for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTint` of the new `DrawableCompat` class (from support v4 lib)

```
// Get the icon you want as a drawable
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_menu, null);
// "Enable" tinting process
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
// Tint it
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.BLACK);
// Set it as action bar icon
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
```

For more details about drawable tinting see [Chris Bane post about support lib V22.1](http://chris.banes.xyz/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/)

Comment: Yes I try this, but now there is no animation